# What is the first movie to show present + flashback in single frame?

Tags: first-appearance

In *[Sahoo (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saaho)*, Ashok describes how shootout happened to police team.
We can see present + flashback in single frame while he describes:

[image]

What is the first movie to show present + flashback in single frame?

Comment: I have not seen that film and I'm therefore a little unclear on what sort of thing you are looking for.  I think you might be talking about the type of scene where someone from the present day is observing the past as if they were an insubstantial and invisible bystander in which case various scenes of Christmas Past from A Christmas Carol adaptions might qualify.  Is that the case?

Comment: @EricNolan Yes! That's my exact case I am asking about.

Comment: The screenshot you're using doesn't clarify what you're looking for at all. Is the man in the front from a different time, in the sense that the people looking at him are looking at the past? Can you clarify your question by adding details, and maybe a link to the scene in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on the idea of A Christmas Carol being a likely candidate I found this video from 1901 via the Wikipedia page.

Most of the footage has apparently been lost but there are scenes in the parts preserved by the British Film Institute that I think meet your criteria.  It's pretty cleverly done when you consider how limited the technology was compared to what is available to film makers now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its the first, but would *Annie  Hall* (1977) be an example of what you're looking for?

Woody Allen sees himself as a child being annoyed by Joey Nichols.

Comment: If A Christmas Carol count; then there are several of those that long pre-date this movie.